# Auto crash of the application with error code 0xc0000005

Tags: crash, dump

There were undefined crashes from the game. There is no specific logic for the application crash. After H, the amount of time always flies to the desktop.
There is no definite logic that may accompany the crash of the game itself.
Game - Grand theft Auto 5

I am attaching the file dump code from the procdump
Help, Guys :)

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.20153.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\*\*\*\*\Procdump\GTA5.exe_210102_114206.dmp]
Comment: '
*** procdump.exe  -accepteula -e -w GTA5.exe C:\*\*\*\*\Procdump
*** Unhandled exception: C0000005.ACCESS_VIOLATION'
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 18363 MP (12 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Sat Jan  2 11:42:06.000 2021 (UTC + 3:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:24.000
................................................................
................................................................
...........................................
Loading unloaded module list
.........
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(2ca8.4828): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
00000001`9647d9da ??              ???
0:099> !analyze -v
ERROR: FindPlugIns 8007007b
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for v8_libplatform.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for v8_libbase.dll

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : AV.Fault
    Value: Execute

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 3843

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on verboten

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 53003

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 422

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Timeline.Process.Start.DeltaSec
    Value: 24

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: rs3_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2017-09-28T15:34:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.16299.15

    Key  : WER.Process.Version
    Value: 1.0.2189.0


ADDITIONAL_XML: 1

OS_BUILD_LAYERS: 1

COMMENT:  
*** procdump.exe  -accepteula -e -w GTA5.exe C:\Users\Influence\Downloads\ìàøèíêè\Procdump
*** Unhandled exception: C0000005.ACCESS_VIOLATION

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=000000019647d9da rbx=0000021315c1a780 rcx=000000d2c828f428
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=000000d2c828f650 rdi=000000000ac3595f
rip=000000019647d9da rsp=000000d2c828f430 rbp=0000000000000008
 r8=000000d2c828f228  r9=000000d2c828f290 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000246 r12=00007ff798a0d110 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000001dac r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010214
00000001`9647d9da ??              ???
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 000000019647d9da
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000008
   Parameter[1]: 000000019647d9da
Attempt to execute non-executable address 000000019647d9da

PROCESS_NAME:  GTA5.exe

EXECUTE_ADDRESS: 19647d9da

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
+0
00000001`9647d9da ??              ???

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 -                      0x%p                               0x%p.                      %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000005

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000008

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000019647d9da

IP_ON_HEAP:  000000019647d9da
The fault address in not in any loaded module, please check your build's rebase
log at <releasedir>\bin\build_logs\timebuild\ntrebase.log for module which may
contain the address if it were loaded.

IP_IN_FREE_BLOCK: 19647d9da

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [ThreadStartAddress] from Frame:[0] on thread:[4828] ; Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

IP_ON_STACK: 
+0
000000d2`c828f650 480000          add     byte ptr [rax],al

FRAME_ONE_INVALID: 1

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 GTA5!Unknown+0x0


SYMBOL_NAME:  GTA5!Unknown+0

MODULE_NAME: GTA5

IMAGE_NAME:  GTA5.exe

STACK_COMMAND:  dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; .ecxr ; ~~[0x4828]s ; .frame 0 ; ** Pseudo Context ** ManagedPseudo ** Value: 245d18ea380 ** ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_c0000005_GTA5.exe!Unknown

OS_VERSION:  10.0.16299.15

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs3_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

IMAGE_VERSION:  1.0.2189.0

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ca327b34-8007-c923-925a-40afa98955f0}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```